# Restrict access to geoserver's web administration interface

Tags: geoserver, security

I am a bit worried because the web administration interface for my geoserver is open to everybody. Of course there is a password set, but I wonder if it is reasonable to block access to the padel from web?

Comment: If you are worry about it, if you believe you must secure your servers as much as possible, then it is reasonable to block its access... Only admins (or even just you!) will be impacted, so it's really an easy choice. If you use NGINX or such, it is fairly easy to open a door just for you and to block access to anybody else.

Comment: just delete the *gui*.jars from the WEB-INF/lib folder